# How do I generate non-duplicated lists of tags used in acts_as_taggable_on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

Two-part question:

I am using acts_as_taggable_on, and I want to generate an array of all the tags used on all the records of a particular Model.  But I want that list to **not** contain duplicates.

When I select a tag, I generate a list of all records that are tagged by that tag.  How do I then generate a list of all the other tags that belong to that list of records (also **not** with duplicates?)

In other words, how do I, for a subset of records, show all the associated tags (minus, of course, the tag that generated that subset?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this answer? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000277

```
a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.uniq!   #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and for your second question http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000273

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] - [ 1, 2, 4 ]  #=>  [ 3, 3, 5 ]
```

Comment: how do I add up all the tags in the array from acts as taggable?